# How to use Login User credentials to call exchange web service in sharepoint for fetching user mail box?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2010

I don't want to use default credentials because I need to fetch log in user Mail Box information therefore, to call Exchange Web Service I need Log in User credentials. So how can I get current Logged-in user credentials??

Constructor of calling exchangeweb service is as below:

```
ExchangeServiceBinding exchangeService = new ExchangeServiceBinding()
exchangeService.RequestServerVersionValue = new RequestServerVersion();
exchangeService.RequestServerVersionValue.Version = ExchangeVersionType.Exchange2010;
exchangeService.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user_LoginID", "LoggedIn_user_password");
```

Answer (score 0):

you can't access the user password or the credentials from SharePoint directly. You're able to get something like SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.LoginName, but you won't be able to hand over the user password, if UseDefaultCredentials doesn't work for the EWS.

Comment: If I use default credentials than i can not get specific users mail box.